# Search/Find FindAccountsForServiceAsync Object reference not set

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019

I have earlier created project in Xamarin visual studio 2017 for and now upgrade it to Visual Studio 2019 lates version 16.3.3.
Currently i am using below version's On MAC

```
xamarin ios - 13.2.0.47
Mono 6.4.0.208
visual studio mac - 8.3.2
```

**code**

```
DriverItemList.RootObject getData = await GetDataFromService(usernameEntry.Text.Trim(), passwordEntry.Text.Trim());

  public static async Task<dynamic> GetDataFromService(string drivernumber, string password)
    {
        try
        {
            var URL = Constants.Url;
            var uri = URL + "api/Drivers/CheckDriverPassword?driverNum=" + System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(drivernumber) + "&pswd=" + System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(password);
            string result = "";

            using (HttpClientHandler ClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler())
            using (HttpClient Client = new HttpClient(ClientHandler))
            {
                Client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
                //var result1 = await Client.GetStringAsync(uri);
                using (HttpResponseMessage ResponseMessage = await Client.GetAsync(uri))
                {
                    if (ResponseMessage.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                        using (HttpContent Content = ResponseMessage.Content)
                        {
                            result = await Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            DriverPass.RootObject posts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DriverPass.RootObject>(result);
            return posts;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return null;
        }
    }
```

I am getting below exception:-

After running the below code i am getting exception 
`

> Message: Search/Find FindAccountsForServiceAsync Object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object InnerMessage:
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object   at
>   Xamarin.Auth.KeyChainAccountStore.m__2 () [0x0000b] in
>   C:\cxa\source\Xamarin.Auth.XamarinIOS\PlatformSpecific\UIViewControllerEx.cs:52
>   at System.Lazy`1[T].ViaFactory (System.Threading.LazyThreadSafetyMode
>   mode) [0x0001c] in
>   /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/external/mono/external/corefx/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Lazy.cs:327
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> at System.LazyHelper.ThrowException () [0x00000] in
>   /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/external/mono/external/corefx/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Lazy.cs:97
>   at System.Lazy`1[T].CreateValue () [0x0007e] in
>   /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/external/mono/external/corefx/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Lazy.cs:435
>   at System.Lazy`1[T].get_Value () [0x00000] in
>   /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/external/mono/external/corefx/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Lazy.cs:509
>   at Xamarin.Auth.KeyChainAccountStore.FindAccountsForServiceAsync
>   (System.String serviceId) [0x00032] in
>   C:\cxa\source\Xamarin.Auth.LinkSource\Evolve16.Labs\AccountManager.cs:57

`

The new code i have added is below:-

```
private void StartTimers()
        {
            if (Constants._UserType != "U")
            {
                double runtime = 3;
                double.TryParse(Constants.LocatinRunTime.ToString(), out runtime);
                var minutes = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(runtime);
                 (int)ConvertMinutesToMilliseconds(Double.Parse(Constants.LocatinRunTime.ToString()));
                // DateTime starttime = DateTime.Now;
                Device.StartTimer(minutes, () =>
                {
                    if (Constants.timerIsRunning == true)
                    {
                        GetPosition();

                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

can you help me to identify and solve this issue.

Comment: Do you change any code before/after update the visual studio? You can try to delete bin/obj folders and rebuild again. I saw someone [report this issue](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth/issues/370) before and it has been fixed in the latest version. Are you using the Xamarin.Auth 1.7.0?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT yes i am using Xamarin.Auth 1.7.0 latest version

Comment: Did you change any code? And can you give us a sample project?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT i change code. i add this one for timer and after comment it is stop to crash Device.StartTimer(minutes, () =>
                {
                    if (Constants.timerIsRunning == true)
                    {
                        GetPosition();
                        
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                });

Comment: Where do you add it? I did not see this line in the code you post in the question.

Comment: i have added the new code in question

Comment: You should check the code in the GetPosition(); and especially  the method of Xamarin.Auth in GetPosition();.